# How to read direct HTML in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Please note that this question is a follow up from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356112/how-to-modify-yahoo-weather-appearance-on-my-page#15356356)

I have the following code (more or less - the data changes regularly) rendering on my page.

```
<div class="weather-feed">
    <img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/28.gif"/><br />
    <b>Current Conditions:</b><br />
    Mostly Cloudy, 19 C<BR />
    <BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />
    Tue - PM Thunderstorms. High: 26 Low: 16<br />
    Wed - Mostly Sunny. High: 27 Low: 16<br />
    <br />
    <a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Pretoria__SF/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/SFXX0044_c.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>
    (provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
</div>
```

I'd like to style this, so I had an idea to modify the rendered HTML by adding in `<div>`s around each section (desired code is in the link to the previous question.

I've written the following jquery (with a lot of help from various people) to get me where I am:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var src = $(".weather-feed");

    // remove line feeds
    var result = src.find("br").remove();


    //var condition = src.html().match(/<b>Current Conditions:<\/b>([^<]*)<b>/)[1].trim());

    // modify weather icon
    result += "<div class=\"weather-icon\"><img src=\"" + src.find("img").attr("src") + "\" /></div>";

    // modify weather conditions
    result += src.find("b:nth-child(1)").before("<div class=\"weather-conditions\">") + ;
    result += src.find("b:eq(1)").before("</div><div class=\"weather-forecast\">");
    result += src.find("a:nth-child(1)").before("</div><div class=\"weather-detail\">");
    result += src.find("a:nth-child(1)").after("</div");

    $("#weather-feed").append(result);
});
```

Currently though, all that's rendering is this exactly:

[object Object]
[image: img]
[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]

I'm not really understanding what exactly it is that jquery is doing here. My goal was to basically get a string representation of the html and replace the html with the modified string.

What it looks like to me is that it's taking the literal html and throwing that on the page... I really don't know though.

So how can I modify this code to write the html code from `src` into `result` where I need it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take html content to process further..

```
var src = $(".weather-feed").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to concatenate a string and a series of jQuery objects. JavaScript is calling the `.toString()` function of said object, which returns `[Object object]`, so that can take place.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that you are appending objects to strings, and thus getting string representations of your objects.

Change what you have to the following,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var src = $(".weather-feed");
    var result = src.find("br").remove();
    result += "<div class=\"weather-icon\"><img src=\"" + src.find("img").attr("src") + "\" /></div>";
    result += src.find("b:nth-child(1)").before("<div class=\"weather-conditions\">").html();
    result += src.find("b:eq(1)").before("</div><div class=\"weather-forecast\">").html();
    result += src.find("a:nth-child(1)").before("</div><div class=\"weather-detail\">").html();
    result += src.find("a:nth-child(1)").after("</div").html();
    $("#weather-feed").append(result);
});
```

This way you are appending the HTML contents found inside each element to the string, which is the result you are looking for.